# bash: find the name of the interpreter

Tags: bash

I have a string with the contents of the first line in a script, eg

```
#!/bin/bash
```

but it can be anything such as

```
#!/path/to/another/interpret -some args -another arg
```

How can I extract the name of the interpreter - "bash", "interpret" by omitting path and arguments?

I though about finding the first whitespace to separate args from the path.

Can you help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'extract'? Where and how do you want to obtain this information? Inside the script?

Comment: Are you sure that a path in a shebang can contain whitespace?

Comment: it's not like i "know how to do it", but, what you can do is use ~some~ command to separate that string regarding "/" as a separator, and use the last value of the resulting string array... i'm guessing sed or awk or grep (and regex) could help you. for instance grep -Po "/[a-z,A-Z]{0-30}$" COULD work, but i'm not sure. Basically that should match "/bash", "/sh", but NOT "/some.thing". Hope this ~kinna~ helps

Comment: Pumbaa80: not really, I'm not sure if that is a requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use white spaces in shebang. If you cannot, you can find the interpreter name like this:

```
interpreter=`cat test.sh | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 1`
basename $interpreter
```

edit:
shorten version:

```
interpreter=$(basename $(sed '2q;s/^#!//;s/ .*//' test.sh))
```

Comment: Could use 'head -n 1 test.sh' directly

Comment: ye, simpler version than the above:

`interpreter=basename \`head -n 1 test.sh\``

Comment: you do need to accommodate whitespace after the `#!` -- `#! /bin/sh` works just fine.

Comment: and here's where you *need* to use `$()` instead of backticks to properly nest the commands: `interpreter=$(basename $(head ...))`

Comment: I didn't know whitespace is allowed after shebang. Then you have to get rid of '#!', otherwise basename takes it as an argument: 

`basename $(echo $(head -n 1 test.sh) | sed s/^#\!//)` works fine

Comment: Argh, don't echo the result of backticks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ basename '#!/path/to/another/interpret -some args -another arg'|awk '{ print $1}'
interpret
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set -- $(head -1 scriptname)
case $1 in
  "#!")
    # whitespace after the #!, the interpreter is the 2nd word
    interp=$2 
    ;;
  "#!"*)
    # no whitespace, strip the first 2 chars from the 1st word
    interp=${1#??}
    ;;
  *)
    echo no shebang at all
    exit
    ;;
esac
interp=$(basename "$interp")
```